# Cut out an UIImage to fit inside an UIImageView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm developing an iOS 4 application.

This question is related to [UIImageView, setClipsToBounds and how my images are losing their head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910517/uiimageview-setclipstobounds-and-how-my-images-are-losing-their-head)

I have the following problem:

On an `UITableViewCell` I have an `UIImageView`. This `UIImageView` is 77x77px and will hold differents **images** size.

I must to process those images in this way:

If an image is 100x120, I need to remove from pixel 78 to pixel 100 (on width), and 78 to 120 (on height). Another option is to create another one cuting out those pixels.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sound like you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set **contentMode** of the image view to **UIViewContentModeTopLeft**.

Hope it will help.

Comment: But, it image's width is less than UIImageView width (or the same width height), how can I scale image? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i have thought you want to cut out (crop) the image, not to resize. So as @Lukas pointed out use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit